# how to add elements of an array in react

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an array of grades from an api but when it try to add them to get the avarege. they get printed instead of added.

**this is the array from the api**

```
grades: (8) ["71", "81", "72", "92", "79", "82", "91", "90"]
```

**My code**

```
 student.grades.map((grades) => {
                      var avarge = 0;
                      avarge = avarge + grades;
                      return avarge;
                    })
```

**Output**

```
071081072092079082091090
```

Comment: You should use reducer instead of the map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
and then divide it on the amount of the elements from that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation versus numerical addition. Using `Number` you can cast number-like strings to a number and addition will now work.

Simple [array::reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce an array of values down to a single value.

```js
const grades = ["71", "81", "72", "92", "79", "82", "91", "90"];

const total = grades.reduce((sum, grade) => sum + Number(grade), 0);

console.log('total', total);
console.log('avg', total / grades.length);
```

Coincidentally you can do some forced conversion as well, by prepending a `+` to the value to force it to a number, but caution should be used.

```js
const grades = ["71", "81", "72", "92", "79", "82", "91", "90"];

const total = grades.reduce((sum, grade) => sum + +grade, 0);

console.log('total', total);
console.log('avg', total / grades.length);
```

Comment: thanks you saved my life. I am working on a challenge. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use ParseInt to typecast the strings, You are trying to add the strings. Convert the strings to either Integers or float using parseInt or parseFloat. Then you can able to add the number strings. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-a-number-and-a-string-in-javascript

```
student.grades.map((grade) => {
  var average = 0;
  average = parseInt(average) + parseInt(grade);
  return average
});
```

[Reduce in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let data = ["71", "81", "72", "92", "79", "82", "91", "90"];
let total = data.reduce(( accumulator, currentValue ) => accumulator + parseInt(currentValue),0);

console.log("Total : "+total)
console.log("Average : "+total / data.length)
```

Comment: this is the output now ```7181729279829190```

Comment: use parseInt to add